# Why does the C++ compiler look in "c:\program files\gnu emacs\include" for include files?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, cmake, libcurl, include-path

I'm trying to compile curl from [source](https://curl.haxx.se/dlwiz/?type=source&os=-) (the zip file) in Windows 10 in order to get the curl library (which in turn is needed to build [osgEarth](http://docs.osgearth.org/en/latest/startup.html#build-it)). However, when I have used CMake to generated the Visual Studio projects and I try to compile the `ALL_BUILD` project using the "default native compiler" (according to CMake), I'm getting a lot of errors, of which the first error says

```
c:\program files\gnu emacs\include\zconf.h(475): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'unistd.h': No such file or directory
```

**Why does the compiler read `c:\program files\gnu emacs\include\zconf.h`?**

To me, it doesn't make any sense that it searches `c:\program files\gnu emacs\include` for include files, since the compilation should be independent of whether emacs is installed (and if it hadn't been installed, this file wouldn't exist). I have searched through all environment variables to se if any of them could be telling the compiler to look in `c:\program files\gnu emacs\include` for include files, but the only environment variables the term `emacs` exists in (case insensitive search) is `PATH` and `ORIGINAL_PATH` (which I don't know what it does).

Is it perhaps something in the CMake project that makes the compiler search this folder?

Answer (score 0):

CMake tries to locate your local zlib install path. There are different possible locations, for more details check `FindZLIB.cmake` somehwere in your cmake install path. My local version will search in `$ZLIB_ROOT` or some windows registry key, maybe one of these variables have been set on your system when installing emacs.